# Как получить конкретные данные из бд?

Tags: python, django

У меня есть три таблицы: Книги, Категории, Подкатегории. Когда юзер переходит по ссылке у меня есть category_id т.е. Категория книг. Как мне получить подкатегории книг, которые пренадлежат к Категории?
Например, в таблице Категория есть художественная литература и документальная литература. В таблице Подкатегории есть все подкатегории данных категорий, они привязаны к одной из категорий. Как мне получить конкретный список подкатегорий?

**views.py**

```
def get_category(request, category_id):
    book = Book.objects.filter(category_id=category_id)
    category = Category.objects.filter(pk=category_id)
    subcategory = Subcategory.objects.filter(pk=???)
    return render(request, 'app/single.html', {'book': book, 'subcategory': subcategory, 
'category': category})
```

**models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey('Subcategory', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=36)

class Subcategory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

тут же все просто, у тебя в Subcategory есть ссылка на таблицу категорий, поэтому и фильтруй по этому полю

```
    subcategory = Subcategory.objects.filter(category=int(category_id))
```

Вот тут, можно подробней посмотреть о различных фильтрах при исопльзовании объектной модели в django
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters

Comment: Знаю что просто, но я еще не силен в этом. Спасибо большое за помощь. Удачи Вам)

Comment: добавил в ответ ссылку на доку, где более подробно описываются различные фильтры. Может будет полезным. Успехов в изучении)